# CQL design for SELECTs with no WHERE

Tags: database-design, cassandra, cql, zebus, nosql

We're currently working on a rewrite of the Directory of our Peer to Peer Service Bus ([Zebus](https://github.com/Abc-Arbitrage/Zebus)).

We had a Cassandra/Thrift implementation and it had to be improved to meet some new load requirements, so rewriting it using CQL seemed to be the right thing to do.

We have two CFs, one to store Peers and one to store Subscriptions, the latter being the trickiest.

We need to store a list of routing keys (bindings) for each message type, and a list of message types for each peer. We also need to be able to update each message type's routings list separately (we use Cassandra's timestamps to handle potential race conditions since we have multiple Directories). And finally, we need to be able to list all those subscriptions when someone requests the Peers state.

The last point was a problem, because it means running a `SELECT * FROM "Subscriptions"`, which means listing rows from multiple nodes (BTW how does CQL allows you to list underlying Cassandra rows?) and happens to be pretty slow.

So we ended up having the following schema for our CF to store everything consecutively on disk on the same Cassandra row and have great read performance (we are aware of the fact that this is pretty bad at balancing the data between nodes).

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "DynamicSubscriptions" (
    "UselessKey" boolean,
    "PeerId" text,
    "MessageTypeId" text,   
    "SubscriptionBindings" blob,
    PRIMARY KEY("UselessKey", "PeerId", "MessageTypeId")
);
```

This is pretty ugly but does the trick, everyone ends up on the same "Thrift row", resulting in lightning fast reads.

So my question is the following: Is there a **pretty** way to design a CF using CQL if I want my data to be queryable really fast during an unconstrained SELECT?

(Or if you think that our design is completely flawed, feel free to say so).

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your data model correctly - for each peer you want to store a list of message types and for each message type you want to store a list of bindings, right? does the list of bindings for a particular message type is defined independently for each peer? The second question - do you want to select all data each time? or data for a single peer?

Comment: Yes we want to store different bindings for a particular message type independently for each peer. Concerning retrieval, we want to be able to select data for a specific peer.

Answer (score 0):

So, as far as I understood it correctly, you should create such table:

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dynamic_subscriptions (
    peer_id        text,
    message_type   text,
    bindings       blob,
    PRIMARY KEY (peer_id, message_type)
);`

It is very similar to your one but the key difference is in primary key definition. 
The first column of the primary key is a partition key, which means that all the data with the same partition key will be stored in the same physical column family row. The rest of the primary key components are clustering columns, which are used to distinguish and sort the data    within a single partition key.

In other words, advantages of this schema are:

- peers data are distributed evenly over the cluster
- you can query for peers data (message types, message types with bindings) efficiently, because they are sorted and stored on a single node
- you can efficiently query for a single message type in the context of particular peer
- you can efficiently update/delete bindings for a selected message type in the context of a particular peer

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Unfortunately this is the first schema I came up with, but the performance of SELECT * with no WHERE constraint was not acceptable, hence the "uglyfication" of my design.

Comment: But, as you said, you are going to retrieve data for a specific peer, aren't you?

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't very clear, what I meant that I need both, for one given Peer AND for all of them.

Comment: Ok, so when you ask for all of them, do you need to get all of them at once or is it ok for you to do some pagination?

Comment: Well, as fast as possible would be best. By pagination, do you mean manually doing multiple queries or using C* 2.0 paging?

Comment: I meant C* 2.0 paging - it should be very fast

Answer (score 0):

Usually there will be a way to restrict the information that is to be perused which is driven by user interaction. This will drive your data model design as well.

One way I can think of restricting the number of peers that you list subscriptions for is based on a time period. Note that this will need to be a separate CF from the one which you query to get per-peer information. The golden rule is one CF drives one query.

Suppose you can restrict the number of peers shown to the user by time, the next problem to solve is distributing the data in more than one partition(Thrift row). You can use a combination of MessageType and a component of time like day as the partition key. When you show this data to the user you have a natural pagination mechanism.

To summarize you will need the CF that Jacek L mentioned. Additionally to show information for multiple peers you could use something like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS peer_subscriptions (
    message_type   text,
    connection_date  text,
    peer_id   text,
    bindings  blob,
    PRIMARY KEY ((message_type,connection_date),peer_id)
);
```